# Using same files for multiple sites (PHP)

Tags: php, include

My goal is to have multiple sites like this:

`www.mysite.com/site1/`

`www.mysite.com/site2/`

`www.mysite.com/site3/`

`www.mysite.com/site4/`

---

The files for the sites are located at:

`www.mysite.com/site_files/`

These include the various pages for the site, as well as the css, js, and images.

---

Each of these pages will be nearly the same, but will load content from a different database, and some coloring, as well as some images, will be different.

I'm just curious as to what the best way of doing this would be. I've tried taking the `index.php` from `www.mysite.com/site_files/` and including it from the `index.php` in on of the sites:

**Contents of a `www.mysite.com/site` index.php:**

```
<?php 

     $siteDB = "this";
     $domainName = "thisdomain";
     $twitterName = "thistwitter";
     $facebookName = "thisfacebook";

     include 'http://www.mysite.com/site_files/index.php'; 

?>
```

Then in site_files index.php I'd have a reference to $siteDB:

```
echo $siteDB;
```

Using this method the variables aren't available to included code.

Each of the sites index.php will have different variables, but they will all include the same `site_files/index.php`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: "I'm just curious as to what the best way of doing this would be"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work:

```
include 'http://www.mysite.com/site_files/index.php';
```

You need to access included files relative to the script. Or by absolute url:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site_files/index.php';
```

Your method is technically functional but you should instead include a nested config file beneath the web root.

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site1_config.php'; 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site_files/index.php';
```

Where the config defines the DB connection and any other site specific details.

This is ONE way to do this and probably the closest to what you have. But not necessarily the "best"

"best" is a matter of opinion in this case.